# Not all lines of grep output returned

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I am writing a shell script to interact with our local Docker repo and have found that I get different results from my bash script than I expect. First, from the command line using:

```
des@dev: docker images | grep gateway
```

I get:

```
test-gateway     4.27.0-1.5.2-301    b215d109c627        8 days ago           1.977 GB
test-gateway     dev                 b215d109c627        8 days ago           1.977 GB
test-gateway     staging             b215d109c627        8 days ago           1.977 GB
test-gateway     4.26.2-1.5.2-298    7376dd26db6e        2 weeks ago          2.117 GB
test-gateway     4.26.2-1.5.2-297    c84e6de5a18e        2 weeks ago          2.117 GB
test-gateway     4.26.0-1.5.2-296    e6a772c0e230        2 weeks ago          2.048 GB
test-gateway     4.24.3-1.5.2-295    d3743f5246f4        3 weeks ago          1.978 GB
test-gateway     prod                d3743f5246f4        3 weeks ago          1.978 GB
test-gateway     4.24.1-1.5.2-294    99065a070172        5 weeks ago          1.908 GB
test-gateway     4.24.1-1.5.2-293    90639b86573a        5 weeks ago          1.908 GB
test-gateway     4.24.1-1.5.2-292    223f8c3a41cf        5 weeks ago          1.908 GB
test-gateway     4.24.0-1.5.2-291    5646792848cf        6 weeks ago          1.873 GB
test-gateway     4.24.0-1.5.2-290    8a4e92f6a7b9        6 weeks ago          1.847 GB
test-gateway     4.24.0-1.5.2-289    475e72c8691e        6 weeks ago          1.847 GB
test-gateway     4.23.8-1.5.2-288    1c83a9f9ccc4        7 weeks ago          1.812 GB
test-gateway     4.23.8-1.5.2-287    5e77c056c703        7 weeks ago          1.812 GB
test-gateway     4.23.7-1.5.2-286    b9d9f95ec17d        7 weeks ago          1.812 GB
test-gateway     4.23.6-1.5.2-282    f40fe68c0183        8 weeks ago          1.997 GB
```

Running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker images | grep gateway | while read line; do
    read line
    echo "$line"
done;
```

Returns:

```
test-gateway     staging             b215d109c627        8 days ago           1.977 GB
test-gateway     4.26.2-1.5.2-298    7376dd26db6e        2 weeks ago          2.117 GB
test-gateway     4.26.0-1.5.2-296    e6a772c0e230        2 weeks ago          2.048 GB
test-gateway     prod                d3743f5246f4        3 weeks ago          1.978 GB
test-gateway     4.24.1-1.5.2-293    90639b86573a        5 weeks ago          1.908 GB
test-gateway     4.24.0-1.5.2-291    5646792848cf        6 weeks ago          1.873 GB
test-gateway     4.24.0-1.5.2-289    475e72c8691e        6 weeks ago          1.847 GB
test-gateway     4.23.8-1.5.2-287    5e77c056c703        7 weeks ago          1.812 GB
test-gateway     4.23.6-1.5.2-282    f40fe68c0183        8 weeks ago          1.997 GB
```

Why doesn't the bash script return all of the matching rows?

NOTE: Just looking at the output I see it appears the script is somehow doing away with lines where the sizes of the images are the same - which makes this even stranger as there is nothing limiting the output in the script.

Comment: Not related to the question, just note, instead of pipe, sometimes is better to write:  `while read ... done < <(docker images | grep gateway)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra `read line` call that is making you skip each line of the results as you parse the output, which needs to be removed.

Also remove an extra layer of sub-shell processing by introducing a simple [process-substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) syntax with a `read` command and while-loop. The syntax basically allows you read from the command output as if it were reading from a file.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done< <(docker images | grep gateway)
```

Comment: *smacks forehead smartly!* Thanks @Inian - I surely missed that!

Comment: @JayBlanchard: It happens ;)